# Ruby on Rails HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-authentication

I am just starting to learn Ruby on Rails and have a newbie question that I have so far been unable to find the answer for. I have a small app that uses HTTP basic authentication and I have design elements in my view that I only want to display if the request is authenticated. How can I access this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the session hash which store data during your session( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm) I will recomend using the following tutorial with Http Basic Auth for generating the form: railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

heres some code you could use

## application_controller

```
  helper_method :admin?
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user_name, password|
      session[:user] = "admin" if user_name == 'admin' && password == 'password' 
    end
  end

private

  def admin?
    session[:user] == "admin"
  end
```